# How to determine file sizes from Plone's ZMI script?

Tags: plone, zope

I have a ZMI script that walks the site recursively to a set depth and prints the URL of files I'm interested in (jpg, gif, png, pdf, etc) via `obj.absolute_url()`. I'd like  to figure out the file size of these files but I am having trouble with that, the object I get back doesn't seem to have any file size call.

My end goal is to figure out where and how large are the larger files I have in Plone.

Answer (score 0):

In Plone you could use `portal_catalog` to search "File" type objects.
Each element in the search is a `brain` object.
Among standard `medatada` returned for every `brain` there is `getObjSize`.

so a call of this may works for you:

```py
for b in portal_catalog(portal_type="File"):
  print "{} - Kb:{}".format(b.r.getPath(), b.getObjSize/1024)
```

[sic] `getPath` is a method and `getObjSize` is actually an attribute

If you have others question please use official community:
http://community.plone.org

Comment: And you do not have to script at all. 

You can achieve your goal through a simple Topic (Collection): searching for File type; enabling "table" view; enabling "getObjSize" in the showed columns.

To enable sorting by "getObjSize" in the criterion section, you have to add it as index though (and than reindex for it).